# Find the maximum k such that it's possible to get a string of 1s after applying the bitwise negation to the substrings of length >= k

Tags: algorithm, binary, bit

You can choose a substring of length >= k unlimited times and apply the bitwise negation to it. The answer is the maximum k that allows to get a string of 1s from the initial string.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What are you own ideas so far? Can you show some code?

Comment: @Ripi2 No, I didn't manage to develop an algorithm. The thing looks like a segment tree if you draw it, but i don't know what to do next and if I'm right

Comment: The point is that most positions in the array will suffer bitwise negation several times, because every position belongs to one or several substrings. So, recursion seems inavoidable.

Comment: Question: Can a "substring" be formed by not-consecutive chars? If not, the solution is easier.

Comment: @Ripi2 It can't be formed by non-consecutive chars by definition

Comment: @Ripi2 I guess it's possible to check if a certain k is suitable using a segment tree, just by inverting the substrings where 0s outnumber 1s. But I doubt it will be efficient enough to built a new tree for each k.

Comment: How would you solve it by hand? Can you design a brute-force way? For example, start with k=n testing all positions to be '1' or negating the whole string. If not, try with all k=n-1 substrings, etc.

Comment: Not clear for me what you callad a bit-wise negation here. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Damien e.g you have a string '1101' and negate its substring [1; 3] => '1010'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say i and j are two indices with different states: true & false. If k is sufficiently large that both i and j are within k of both end of the string, then there is no way to get them both to be true. Thus k must be small enough that for every pair of mismatched bits, it's possible to flip just one of them.

If the question is to find a value of k that will work with any string of length n, use `k=ceil(n/2)`. You can easily get half of it to be all the same by using a sliding window of size k to flip bits, and once that's done you can use larger windows to fix the remaining bits. Once all bits are identical, flip or not as needed.

E.g. 1010100101, n=10, so we use k=5.

```
I'll mark flipped bits in brackets
 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
 1[1 0 1 0 1]0 1 0 1
 1 1[1 0 1 0 1]1 0 1
 1 1 1[1 0 1 0 0]0 1
 1 1 1 1[1 0 1 1 1]1
Now that the left half is identical, we'll start using larger ranges
[0 0 0 0 0]0 1 1 1 1]
...and we finish with:
[1 1 1 1 1 1]1 1 1 1
```

We can get away with k > n/2 if the area that is within both k from the left and k from the right is identical, otherwise we can't. The latter is clear, because every flip must include all these bits so if they're mismatched they will always stay mismatched.

If the overlap area is identical, proceed as above, starting from the left

E.g. 0100000001. Here we can use k=8, because the intersection of the bits 8 from the left and 8 from the right are identical.

```
 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
[1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1]0 1
 1[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]1
 1 1[1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 Now that we have k 1s from one edge, we expand our flipping area as before
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]0 0
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
...and we're done.
```

Comment: Since all you need is the maximum k, take n/2 + radius of identical elements around center.